# In Eclipse, how can I add a toolbar button to run a batch file?

Tags: java, eclipse

Say I have a batch file `C:\myscript.bat`, how can I add a toolbar button to eclipse that runs the batch file when I press the button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under *Run -> External Tools -> External Tools Configurations...*, you can define any external program, including Windows batch files.

Once defined, *Run -> External Tools -> (name of script) will run your batch file. So will left clicking on the arrow to the right of the Run icon on the tool bar and left clicking on the name of your script.