# Eclipse: Is there a way to quickly export JARs

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So this may seem a bit vague, how quick is "quick" etc.

Well I'm just wondering if there is a way of exporting a JAR file in a quicker way than:

`File -> Export -> JAR File` etc etc.

Like can I `Ctrl + Drag` to explorer and it export with the project title and `.jar`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How to add custom shortcuts

> To add or change shortcuts open: Windows->Preferences->General->Keys.
>   Here you can find all the Eclipse commands and their associated
>   shortcut keys.

[Reference](http://idiot2genius.wordpress.com/2011/04/10/eclipse-ide-custom-shortcut-keys/)

You can add a custom binding in eclipse to export your jar using a keyboard shortcut.

***Example***

I added bindings both for Runnable and non-runnable jar:

- Export Jar: CTRL+SHIFT+J
- Export Runnable Jar: CTRL+SHIFT+R

[image]

### How to do with Ant File

If you want the JAR to be generated automatically you can look at the following question:

- [Build project into a JAR automatically in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062941/build-project-into-a-jar-automatically-in-eclipse)

### How to do with Batch file run from Button

You can use the combination of the following two answers:

- [Create jar file from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243442/create-jar-file-from-command-line)
- [In Eclipse, how can I add a toolbar button to run a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045705/in-eclipse-how-can-i-add-a-toolbar-button-to-run-a-batch-file)

Basically create a batch file that makes the JAR... add a button that executes it.

Comment: Is there any way to then make it so that it when I press those keys is names the file the project name and saves it in the previous location

Comment: So you mean do a key combination and export directly in one step?

Comment: Maybe this will work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12200309/1688441 . Otherwise, a custom eclipse plugin OR a button in your GUI that calls a bat file that does the jar export.

Comment: Yes that exactly what I mean

Answer (score 2):

If using Maven a long term option would be to set up your build to 'package' your jar.  Then just run the mvn package command from the command line or using the Eclipse Maven plugin.  This method requires some upfront work, but it buys you a consistent and easy jar export.