# Jar Export Shortcut Key in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I need to know the **Jar Exporting Shortcut Key in Eclipse** to destination.I don't know if it is possible or not.

I am export jar file now Right click on Project folder and select export then select JAR like this way.But  i feel to difficult every day using like this.

So Can you please suggest me any shortcut key for export jar file in eclipse.

Comment: That export wizard has an option to save the process as an Ant script, I think. You make that and run it. Do that once, and it should appear as a Run button entry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: Is there a way to quickly export JARs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688134/eclipse-is-there-a-way-to-quickly-export-jars)

Answer (score 6):

At present, there is no predefined keyboard shortcut for exporting Jar.

### Solution

Add a custom shortcut in **Windows->Preferences->General->Keys** by defining a [Custom key binding](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftips%2Fjdt_tips.html)

All the Eclipse commands and their associated shortcut keys are displayed here. You can use the predefined ones or assign/change new shortcuts here.

[image]

After assigning the shortcut, it will show the user defined key binding.
For me it shows  my custom combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> as follows:

[image]